# How do you query for WMI namespaces?

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

How do you query for WMI namespaces?

So I know about WMI namespaces because I read that they exits and I know I can connect to say:

```
root\cimv2
```

My question is what if I didn't know what namespaces were there, how would I go about querying for the available namespaces?

I just sort of want to go exploring the WMI and not have to look up each namespace.

I'm using WBEMtest, but I'll take anything, .NET, winapi.h, what have you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enumerate all the namespaces, you must first connect to the `root` namespace, query for all the `__NAMESPACE` instances, and for each instance recursively repeat this process.

check these samples

**Delphi**

```
procedure  GetListWMINameSpaces(const RootNameSpace:String;const List :TStrings;ReportException:Boolean=True);//recursive function
var
  objSWbemLocator : OleVariant;
  objWMIService   : OleVariant;
  colItems        : OLEVariant;
  colItem         : OLEVariant;
  oEnum           : IEnumvariant;
  iValue          : LongWord;
  sValue          : string;
begin
 try
  objSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  objWMIService   := objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(wbemLocalhost, RootNameSpace, '', '');
  colItems        := objWMIService.InstancesOf('__NAMESPACE');
  oEnum           := IUnknown(colItems._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, colItem, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    sValue:=VarStrNull(colItem.Name);
    colItem:=Unassigned;
    List.Add(RootNameSpace+'\'+sValue);
    GetListWMINameSpaces(RootNameSpace+'\'+sValue,List);//recursive
  end;
 except
     if ReportException then
     raise;
 end;
end;
```

**VbScript**

```
strComputer = "."
Call EnumNameSpaces("root")

Sub EnumNameSpaces(strNameSpace)
    WScript.Echo strNameSpace
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & _
        "\" & strNameSpace)
    Set colNameSpaces = objWMIService.InstancesOf("__NAMESPACE")
    For Each objNameSpace In colNameSpaces
        Call EnumNameSpaces(strNameSpace & "\" & objNameSpace.Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 15):

I understand that you got your answer but wanted to show how easy it is in PowerShell to get a list of namespaces:

```
Get-WMIObject -namespace "root" -class "__Namespace" | Select Name
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python (with the requisite WMI and pyWin32 extensions installed):

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI (moniker='//./root')
wql = "SELECT * FROM __NAMESPACE"

for __NAMESPACE in c.query(wql):
    print __NAMESPACE.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

To list all the namespace `Name` property values for all (root) namespaces for a server named *server* in C# (in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)):

```
ManagementClass nsClass =
    new ManagementClass(
        new ManagementScope(@"\\server\root"),
        new ManagementPath("__namespace"),
        null);

foreach(ManagementObject ns in nsClass.GetInstances())
{
    ns["Name"].Dump();
}
```

Note that the `Dump` method just outputs a value; if you're not using LINQPad you'd want to do something else with the `Name` property value.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * FROM __NAMESPACE" -Namespace "root"` from powershell.

This also works for Windows Nano Server

Answer (score 0):

You can use **VBScript** to get all `Namespaces` from `root`.

*Here is the sample script*

```
On Error Resume Next
strComputer = "." 
Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
Wscript.Echo "Namespaces"
Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM __NAMESPACE",,48) 
For Each objItem in colItems 
    Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name
Next
```

*Expected output*

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

-----------------------------------
Namespaces
-----------------------------------
Name: subscription
Name: DEFAULT
Name: MicrosoftWmiNet
Name: CIMV2
Name: Cli
Name: nap
Name: MicrosoftIISv2
Name: SECURITY
Name: SecurityCenter2
Name: RSOP
Name: WebAdministration
Name: WMI
Name: OpenHardwareMonitor
Name: directory
Name: Policy
Name: Interop
Name: ServiceModel
Name: SecurityCenter
Name: Microsoft
Name: aspnet
```