# WMI Namespaces - Is There An 'Official List'?

Tags: windows-xp, wmi

I'm (unfortunately) venturing into Windows (XP) scripting and WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) as I am attempting to write scripts that will configure such things as network adapters, users etc.

Key to this seems to be the so-called WMI 'Namespaces'; once one has the name spaces apparently it's possible to discover classes within the namespace and read/alter data as necessary. (Apologies if I have misunderstood anything about WMI & namespaces).

So the obvious question is, just what WMI namespaces are available? It's fine being able to write a script that lists them but where is the official Microsoft list of namespaces? How on earth are you supposed to know what:

1. Namespaces official exist?
2. What classes are under each namespace?
3. Where do I look for a specific class say for network settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.Namespaces official exist?**

AFAIK there is not a official list of WMI namespaces, but you can get the [list of installed namespaces programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332501/how-do-you-query-for-wmi-namespaces).

**2.What classes are under each namespace?**

Again there isn't a official list, but you can get this list connecting to each namespace and then executing this WQL sentence

```
select * from meta_class
```

**3.Where do I look for a specific class say for network settings?**

Take a look to the MSDN documentation [`Windows Management Infrastructure Classes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394554%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If you need more information about the WMI classes and namespaces I will recommend you use a tool like the [`WMI Delphi Code Creator`](http://code.google.com/p/wmi-delphi-code-creator/), this tool allows you to generate code to access the WMI classes, events and methods. Also includes a set of options to search classes related to a specific keyword, execute WQL sentences, get metadata info about any WMI class and so on.

Comment: Hi RRUZ, thanks for your answer. I must have a misunderstanding about namespaces? I assumed they were a list of Microsoft defined 'packages' if you will, therefore could be referred to by means of documentation?

Answer (score 4):

I created the list, you can see it at http://wutils.com/wmi/namespaces.html. It is not official list, of course. It contains list of namespaces in plain installation of Windows server with some extensions (sql server, exchange) and list of classes/properties/methods in each of the namespace.

Comment: Very nice. I hope other people find your work useful.

Comment: Wow what an awesome resource! You deserve a TON more up votes.